# how to make the character changing in my email subject?

Tags: python-2.7, decode, imaplib

I login into my gmail account and print all my email sujects.

```
import imaplib
import email
user="xxxx"
password="yyyy"
con=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
con.login(user,password)
num=int(con.select("[Gmail]/&YkBnCZCuTvY-")[1][0])                     
for item in range(1,num+1):
    result,data=con.fetch(str(item), '(RFC822)')
    print email.message_from_string(data[0][1])["Subject"]
```

The result are :

```
    =?GB2312?B?R29vZ2xlINXKu6fD3MLr0tG4/LjE?=
    =?utf-8?Q?=E3=80=8A=E4=B8=AD=E5=9B=BD=E6=95=B0=E5=AD=97=E6=97=B6=E4=BB=A3=E3=80=8B=E6=AF=8F=E6=97=A5=E7=94=B5=E9=82=AE=202015=2F01=2F10?=
```

how can i change the string encoded with gb2312 and utf-8 into normal chinese characters ?